# Sql server query to flattening a hierarchy of records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, hierarchy

I have a table that describes a hierarchy:

```
Name    MemberName
A       B
A       C
B       D
D       E
F       G
```

MemberName references the Name column of the same table.  From this table, I can easily query to see that B and C are members within A, D is a member of B, E is a member of D and G is a member of F.

Based on this structure it's difficult to write a query that shows that D, and E are also indirectly a member of A.  D and E are also indirectly a member of B, etc.  So what I need to do is build up a new table that shows shows all the indirect members.  So for the above table data, I'd end up with a table containing:

```
Name    MemberName
A       B
A       C
A       D
A       E
B       D
B       E
D       E
F       G
```

I started by putting all the records that weren't members of other records (top level) records) into a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP
(
    [Name] varchar(20),
    [MemberName] varchar(20)
)

DECLARE @iRowsFound INT
INSERT INTO #TMP ([Name],[MemberName]) 
(SELECT * FROM [HierarchyData] WHERE [Name] NOT IN 
   (SELECT [MemberName] FROM [HierarchyData]))
SELECT @iRowsFound = @@ROWCOUNT

Name    MemberName
A       B
A       C
F       G
```

Then my theory was to, in a while loop, cross join the temp table to the heirachy table and insert the applicable records from the cross join back into the temp table, and perform that while loop until there were no more applicable records in the cross join to insert:

```
WHILE (@iRowsFound > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TMP ([Name],[MemberName]) 
    (
        SELECT 
            [NewName] = ??,
            [NewMember] = ??
        FROM
            [HierarchyData],[#TMP]
        WHERE
            ???        
    )
    SELECT @iRowsFound = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

I'm just not sure I'm on the right track, as I'm a little stumped as to what the cross join select should look like.  Has anyone done something like this (in sql server 2000)?

**Edit:  I think I may have gotten it:** - Although I'm pretty sure there must be a 
more efficient way to do this...

```
WHILE (@iRowsFound > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TMP ([Name],[MemberName]) 
    (       
            SELECT
                --[#TMP].[Name],
                --[#TMP].[MemberName],
                [HierarchyData].[Name],
                [HierarchyData].[MemberName]
            FROM 
                [#TMP]
            JOIN 
                [HierarchyData] ON [#TMP].[MemberName] = [HierarchyData].[Name]
            --WHERE
            --  [#TMP].[MemberName] = [HierarchyData].[Name]
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [#TMP] WHERE [#TMP].[Name] = [HierarchyData].[Name] AND [#TMP].[MemberName] = [HierarchyData].[MemberName])   
            UNION   
            SELECT
                [#TMP].[Name],
                --[#TMP].[MemberName],
                --[HierarchyData].[Name],
                [HierarchyData].[MemberName]
            FROM 
                [#TMP]
            JOIN 
                [HierarchyData] ON [#TMP].[MemberName] = [HierarchyData].[Name]     
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [#TMP] WHERE [#TMP].[Name] = [#TMP].[Name] AND [#TMP].[MemberName] = [HierarchyData].[MemberName])    

    )
    SELECT @iRowsFound = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes your code will work, but it does a lot of extra work than having the cycle var in the temp table like my code does.  Since you have to do 4 select statements per cycle not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an SQL 2000 version.

Some notes: This will work with any numbers of levels and will not have cycle errors (like the CTE versions will.)

```
declare @lastcount int
declare @lastcycle int

Select HierarchyData.Name, HierarchyData.MemberName, 0 as [Cycle] INTO #list
FROM HierarchyData

SET @lastcount = @@rowcount
SET @lastcycle = 0

while @lastcount > 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #list
    SELECT Members.Name, Child.MemberName as [MemberName], @lastcycle+1 as [Cycle]
    FROM #list Members
    JOIN HierarchyData Child ON Members.MemberName = Child.Name
    LEFT JOIN #list cycletest ON Members.Name = cycletest.Name AND Child.MemberName = cycletest.Membername
    WHERE Members.Cycle = @lastcycle AND NOT (Members.Name = Child.MemberName) AND cycletest.Name is null

  SET @lastcount = @@rowcount

  SET @lastcycle = @lastcycle + 1
END

SELECT [Name], [MemberName] FROM #list
ORDER BY [Name], [MemberName]

DROP TABLE #list

---- Test data
--create table HierarchyData
--(
--  [Name] varchar(20),
--  [MemberName] varchar(20)
--)
--
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('A','B')
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('A','C')
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('B','D')
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('D','E')
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('F','G')
----CYCLE TEST  (the CTE will not work)
--INSERT INTO HierarchyData (Name,MemberName) Values('E','D')
--
---- Test
--select * from HierarchyData

---- CTE Works (note, will fail on cycles.)
--WITH Members AS
--(
--  Select HierarchyData.Name, HierarchyData.MemberName 
--  FROM HierarchyData
--  UNION ALL
--  SELECT Members.Name, Child.MemberName as [MemberName]
--  FROM Members
--  JOIN HierarchyData Child ON Members.MemberName = Child.Name
--)
--SELECT * FROM Members
--ORDER BY [Name], [MemberName]
```

Answer (score 6):

So sad you are not on sql server 2005 or later, it is easy with a recursive CTE  the code is here:

```
WITH Members AS
(
  Select Name, MemberName 
  FROM HierarchyData
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Name, Child.MemberName as [MemberName]
  FROM Members
  JOIN HierarchyData Child ON Members.MemberName = Child.Name
)
SELECT * FROM Members
```

In 2000 you can do it basically the same way (joining the results of the last select to the original table till you have no results of the last set inside a loop), but it is much harder because you have to keep track of what iteration you are on via a counter.  Yuck.

Does this help, or do you want some sql 2000 pseudo code?

Better yet, just upgrade!

Comment: @Jim : hmmm... It seems I said that in the first line.  AND my answer is also the accepted answer.  I left BOTH answers in the question because if someone reads this question who has 2005 (and we can expect that more and more as time passes), they will know how to do it in their version of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following code pattern to follow a hierarchy in SQL Server 2000.  The "magic" is adding the depth value to the temporary table so you can use that in the WHERE clause.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #super_trees
(
    supervisor_uid  INTEGER,
    actor_uid       INTEGER,
    depth           INTEGER
)

DECLARE
    @more_users BIT,
    @depth      INTEGER

SET @more_users = 1
SET @depth      = 0

INSERT INTO #super_trees VALUES (@supervisor_uid, @supervisor_uid, @depth)

SET @depth = @depth + 1

WHILE (@more_users = 1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #super_trees (supervisor_uid, actor_uid, depth)
        SELECT u.supervisor_uid,
               u.actor_uid,
               @depth
          FROM #super_trees sr
           INNER JOIN
           dbo.users u
           ON (sr.actor_uid = u.supervisor_uid)
         WHERE sr.depth = (@depth - 1)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1
        SET @more_users = 0

    SET @depth = @depth + 1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE above does not meet the objective of the poster. He/she wants to flatten the data. CTE only returns hierarchy information with different values under the ParentID column.

Name    MemberName
A       B
A       C
B       D
D       E
F       G

So the above is what you get using CTE, NOT

Name    MemberName
A       B
A       C
A       D
A       E
B       D
B       E
D       E
F       G

Comment: I think you need to format this so it is clear... indent or use the code button on the editor.  Also, the order of the questions can change so saying above is not clear -- you have to use the person's name.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to make a slight alteration to your data. You do not have a record that says that A is the root of the hierarchy. Adding that:

```
INSERT INTO #TMP(Name, MemberName) VALUES (NULL, 'A')
```

greatly simplifies things (also, typically, the adjacency list would be represented 'the other way around': a column `Name`, and a column `ParentName` which would correspond to your `MemberName`, `Name` columns respectively.

With that setup you can use a *common table expression* to do the job:

```
WITH Node (Name, ParentName)
AS  (
    SELECT     Name, ParentName
    FROM       Tab
    WHERE      ParentName IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     Tab.Name, Tab.ParentName
    FROM       Tab
    INNER JOIN Node
    ON         ParentName = Node.Name
    )
SELECT Name, ParentName
FROM   Node
```

Unfortunately, common table expressions are supported in MS SQL 2005 and up as pointed out by Hogan.

Comment: I don't think A is the root -- all elements in the starting table are the root.

Comment: I don't have control over the schema of the HierarchyData table.  I'm also limited to SQL 2000.